# AS3 import class not working

Tags: class, actionscript-3, flash

I'm lost.  For the life of me I can't seem to create and import my own class.  I've read so many posts and on it and even followed tutorials (which have worked fine), but now that it's all my original work, no dice!

So, my .as file named GeoMath, which contains the class I'd like to import, looks like this:

```
package {

public class GeoMath {

    public function GeoMath() {
        // Get Distance Between 2 points.
        public function distance(x1: Number, x2: Number, y1: Number, y2: Number): Number {
            var d: Number;
            d = Math.pow(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2), .5);
            return d;
        }... etc.
```

and this .as file is in the same folder as my .fla file.  Incidentally, it also has another two .as files that have `Sprite` extensions that I am successfully instantiating.  Ok, now the main class:

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.*;

import GeoMath; // C:\Users\User\Desktop\oldProjects\oldProject_1
    ...
public class Document extends MovieClip {
    ...    
    mouseVel = distance(me.stageX, mouseLastX, me.stageY, mouseLastY);
```

`...Document.as, Line 174, Column 17    1180: Call to a possibly undefined method distance.`

I have tried putting a folder called 'calculations' in the same folder as the .fla, and then putting GeoMath.as in THAT folder, and then doing this in the GeoMath.as file:

```
package calculations {
...
```

and in the main class doing this:

```
import calculations.GeoMath
```

but this has returned the same results.  I'm I blind or just stupid?  Thanks for taking a look.  It will be much appreciated as I'm bleeding out of my eyes by now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call the function without instantiating a copy of GeoMath, you need to make it static.

`public static function distance(x1: Number, x2: Number, y1: Number, y2: Number): Number {`

and the function call would change to...

`mouseVel = GeoMath.distance(me.stageX, mouseLastX, me.stageY, mouseLastY);`

However, that has other ramifications.  Therefore, make sure you instantiate the class and call the method of the instance.

```
var myGeoMath:GeoMath = new GeoMath();
mouseVel = myGeoMath.distance(me.stageX, mouseLastX, me.stageY, mouseLastY);
```

As for your class import, you have the right idea, though you can change the location of your classes by adding the path in: `Advanced ActionScript 3.0 Settings` > `Source path`.  From there, hit the plus symbol and add the base path.

[image: example of AS3 settings panel]

You'll notice that the default path is simply `.`, which ensures the `.fla` searches for classes in the same folder.  If you want to go up a directory, you can use relative paths with `../`, just like on the web.  In any case, from that location it will search for your `namespace.package.class`

For example, `flash.display.MovieClip` is literally 2 folders and an `.as` file in this format:

```
SOURCE PATH
↪   flash/
    ↪   display/
        ↪   MovieClip.as
            Shape.as
            Sprite.as
            ...
```

It's wise to keep your classes in your own namespace (as it helps prevent collisions).  Your package may look like `package nealdavis.calculations {` and your class would be `public class GeoMath {`. You would then need a similar folder structure...

```
SOURCE PATH
    document.fla
↪   nealdavis/
    ↪   calculations/
        ↪   GeoMath.as
            ...
```

Comment: I just added a section on class pathing.  Could you try that, and if it doesn't address it, update your original question with the issue?  Alternatively, you may want to open a new question if the issue is distinctly different.  Don't forget to accept, if this one fixed the original issue. :)

Comment: Thanks so much!  I've done this, but I get the error: `C:\Users\User\Desktop\oldProjects\oldProject_1\calculations\GeoMath.as, Line 1, Column 1 5001: The name of package 'calculations' does not reflect the location of this file. Please change the package definition's name inside this file, or move the file. C:\Users\User\Desktop\oldProjects\oldProject_1\calculations\GeoMath.as
` .  I think it will be better to post a new question.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, even with following your exact folder scheme.  So I've added a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096892/as3-trying-to-import-a-custom-class-files-in-wrong-order).  Maybe you can take a look?  Thanks.

Comment: @NealDavis "*even with following your exact folder scheme*" no you're not. You are adding the folder `nealdavis/` to the source path, but it's actually part of the package. With a folder structure like `C:/as3/nealdavis/calculations/GeoMath.as` your source path should be `C:/as3` **not** `C:/as3/nealdavis`. Subfolders of the source path are packages.

Comment: Thanks for you help, it got me started in the right direction, so I'll mark this as solved, but final piece to the puzzle (for anyone else having this same issue), is to make sure that I don't put the functions I'm trying to use in the GeoMath class IN the constructor code.  Apparently they have to be in the same .as file as the GeoMath constructor, but not IN the constructor.  Also, they need to be `public function ...`.