# AS3 trying to import a custom class. Files in wrong order?

Tags: actionscript-3

I posted my original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096307/as3-import-class-not-working). Which got me to this point.  I think I'm doing everything just as @Atriace suggested, but I get this error:
`C:\Users\User\Desktop\oldProjects\nealdavis\calculations\GeoMath.as, Line 1,       Column 1    5001: The name of package 'nealdavis.calculations' does not reflect the location of this file. Please change the package definition's name inside this file, or move the file. C:\Users\User\Desktop\oldProjects\nealdavis\calculations\GeoMath.as`

[image: AS3 advanced settings]

[image: GeoMath package]

[image: main package]

[image: folder order]

Since, I think I'm doing everything as I've been suggested to, I thought I'd upload the screenshots.  Maybe there is something amiss that I don't even know to tell you about.  Thanks.

Comment: Try to verify the path of your class file (`nealdavis\calculations`) and its package (`nealdavis.calculations`) maybe you have forgot something or you have some typing error, save all your `.as` files and test again ...

Comment: I meant to have this picture of the file folder here (which I've now added).  I'll try changing all the names and saving to a different file folder, I guess, but does anything look wrong with my file folders?  (GeoMath.as is in the 'calculations' folder.

Comment: As your `Document.as` is also inside the `nealdavis` dir, you can do : `import calculations.GeoMath;` and the package of the `GeoMath` class will be just `calculations` : `package calculations { /* ... */ }` ...

Comment: I get this error: `C:\Users\User\Desktop\oldProjects\nealdavis\Document.as, Line 176, Column 27 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method distance through a reference with static type calculations:GeoMath.
` when I do that.  Line 176 looks like this: `mouseVel = myGeoMath.distance(me.stageX, mouseLastX, me.stageY, mouseLastY);`  I've double checked spelling and folder locations and resaved everything.

Comment: So, I think this means that there is a problem with how I'm calling the functions from within my Document Class or else I'm writing them wrong in my GeoMath class?  Something to do with scope? Public/private? Static vs. dynamic?  I've tried as many permutations as I can think of.

Comment: Your `GeoMath.distance()` method should be outside the class constructor ...

Comment: what do you mean? Can you elaborate? Are you referring to when I call the function, it has to be outside my main Document class?
Or it has to be written in the GeoMath.as but outside the GeoMath constructor?
Sorry, but I feel like I've tried everything

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I was speaking about defining that method, it should be outside the `GeoMath` constructor which is the case now according to your 2nd image (of the `GeoMath` class) ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AS3 import class not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096307/as3-import-class-not-working)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your other question. **Don't post your question twice!** If you do not understand an answer ask in the comments of that answer.

Comment: I did. And he suggested I post a new question

Comment: But only if the question is distinctly different. This one is not.

Comment: @akmozo You were correct!  This was my problem!  So I just have an empty constructor, and then a collection of `public function ...` after the GeoMath constructor opens and closes.  Great catch.  Sorry to everyone for the wild goose chase!  I was losing my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your **tutorialAsteriod** file can only see a sub-folder called **calculations** when it tries to compile. Yet your **Document.as** code tells it to :

`import nealdavis.calculations.GeoMath;`.

With that line, it is expected that **Document.as** is in the same location as a sub-folder called **nealdavis** which in turns contains that **calculations** sub-folder inside. You only have a sub-folder called **calculations** hence you get the error.

**To Fix :**
Either make a new extra sub-folder called **nealdavis** and then move that **calculations** folder into it so that the final setup is : 
`Document.as` + folder called `nealdavis` + inside that will be `calculations` sub-folder.

Your folder structure should be like this example : 
**Desktop > oldProjects > nealdavis >** (Document.as here... + ) **nealdavis > calculations**

Or else just do : `import calculations.GeoMath;`.

Comment: I tried that too. I'll even upload a screen capture of that attempt when I get home tonight.

Comment: It might be because (in your first top picture) you have 3 folder paths listed. I would expect to see just only the first one (folder icon with a `.` and not needing the following two folder paths listed below that).

Comment: Once I had all my folders in the correct locations, it still wasn't working with an error that said my functions weren't accessible.  Finally, everything worked when I combined your answer here, with the last comment by @akmozo above (my functions I was trying to access were nested inside the constructor of the GeoMath class, which is apparently wrong).  Also, the functions need to be `public function...`.